# How to get 2D Javascript Game Script to run on a React Page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web3js

I have an HTML website that plays a game that's programmed completely in javascript. I am trying to convert the website from an HTML layout, to a more modern React layout, and cannot figure out how to get the game to render.

In the HTML version, I have the following code to load in the game scripts to the page:

```js
window.addEventListener('loadGameEngine', loadGameEngine); 

async function loadGameEngine() {
  window.removeEventListener('loadGameEngine', loadGameEngine); 
  const canvas = document.getElementById("playground");
  const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  const map = new GameMap(canvas); 
  const loader = new Loader(); 
  await loader.init(); 
  const renderer = new Renderer(context, map, loader); 
  const mouse = new Mouse(canvas); 
  const ui = new UI(canvas, context, loader, mouse); 
  const economics = new Economics(map); 

  const game = new Game(canvas, renderer, ui, map, mouse); 
  game.init(); 
}
```

And then in the body of the Game HTML page, I have this:

```html
    <div class="body">
      <div class="Game__container">
        <div class="canvas">
          <canvas
            id="playground"
            width="1152"
            height="576"
            class="game"
          ></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Engine/main.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Blockchain/web3.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="Scripts/Blockchain/metamask.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried multiple different ways to load in the scripts in my React project, but the Main script never seems to run. I have tried adding the scripts to the index.html of the React project, like so:

```html
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="../src/Scripts/Engine/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="../src/Scripts/Blockchain/metamask.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="../src/Scripts/Blockchain/web3.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
```

I have also tried loading in the scripts directly to the React page using a react hook function, like so:

```js
const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    script.type = "text/babel";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]);
};
```

And then calling `useScript` in the Game component. I can see the scripts both ways when I inspect element on my local web server. Here is the code for my Game component:

```
const Game = props => {

  useScript("../../Scripts/Engine/main.js");
  useScript("../../Scripts/Blockchain/web3.js");
  useScript("../../Scripts/Blockchain/metamask.js");
  useScript("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/web3@latest/dist/web3.min.js");

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ margin: "6px 0px" }}>
        Gaming
      </div>

      <div className="body">
        <div className="Game__container">
          <div className="canvas">
            <canvas
              id="playground"
              width="1152"
              height="576"
              className="game"
            ></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading your scripts as you would do in HTML, `export` your classses and functions from your files and then `import` them into your `App.js` file at the very top:

First export correct functions and classes (I don't know how your file looks so you will need to show it or figure it out yourself) from your files:

```
// in the file Scripts/Engine/main.js
export { map, Economics, game }

// in the file Scripts/Blockchain/web3.js
export { renderer, mouse, ui, loader }
```

And then import it into your main `App.js` file:

```
import { map, Economics, game } from "Scripts/Engine/main.js"
import { renderer, mouse, ui, loader } from "Scripts/Blockchain/web3.js"
import /* your stuff */ from "Scripts/Blockchain/metamask.js"
```

And then inside the same component call `useEffect` hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const canvas = document.getElementById("playground");
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const map = new GameMap(canvas); 
    const loader = new Loader(); 
    await loader.init(); 
    const renderer = new Renderer(context, map, loader); 
    const mouse = new Mouse(canvas); 
    const ui = new UI(canvas, context, loader, mouse); 
    const economics = new Economics(map); 

    const game = new Game(canvas, renderer, ui, map, mouse); 
    game.init();
}, []}
```

This will load your scripts at the moment of rendering your page, but will init them as soon as your component is rendered properly.

You can also make an improvement to get things done as you would typically do it in react. On the top of your component create variable `const canvasRef = useRef(null)`, swap `const canvas = document.getElementById("playground")` with `const canvas = canvasRef.current`, and in your `return` statement add `ref` to canvas: `<canvas ref={canvasRef}></canvas>`